# Unable to collect vCPUs usage from metric query language MQL - GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, monitoring, mql, vcpu

I'm trying to get vCPUs usage (how many vCPUs are used right now) by the following query:

```
vCPUUsageMonitoringQuery = "fetch consumer_quota\n| metric 'serviceruntime.googleapis.com/quota/allocation/usage' | filter (resource.service == 'compute.googleapis.com') && (metric.quota_metric == 'compute.googleapis.com/cpus')| group_by 10000s, [value_usage : max(value.usage)]  | every 5m | within d'2022/04/13-08:40:00', d'2022/04/13-08:50:00'"
```

if I decrease the value for the 'group_by' field, I do not get back the vCPU's num.
What is the right query to get the current vCPUs number that are being used right now?

Comment: Try using this metric `compute.googleapis.com/instance/cpu/reserved_cores` to get Number of vCPUs reserved on the host of the instance. Refer this [document](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#gcp-compute) for more information on defined metrics of Compute Engine.

Comment: fetch consumer_quota
| metric 'serviceruntime.googleapis.com/quota/allocation/usage' 
| filter (resource.service == 'compute.googleapis.com') && (metric.quota_metric == 'compute.googleapis.com/instance/cpu')
| group_by 24543s, [value_usage : max(value.usage)]
returns nothing

Comment: There is a [Feature Request](https://b.corp.google.com/issues/143543111)  for this issue and there is no ETA at this moment. you can follow this bug for further updates on this issue.

Comment: @GoliNikitha Thanks! I need to login with SSO in order to see this feature request. Is there another way to see the feature request?

Comment: SSO is only way to see the Feature Request.